# Format JSON Objects to an array of JSON Objects

Tags: php, arrays, json, slim

I've been searching Google for a while now, but haven't come close to what I'm looking for.

From the REST API on the server, I'm getting back this response:

`{"hours":6,"day":"FRI"}{"hours":3,"day":"WEDS"}{"hours":6,"day":"MON"}{"hours":9,"day":"THUR"}{"hours":12,"day":"TUES"}{"hours":3,"day":"FRI"}`

Which is just one long string of JSON Objects. How would I get these objects to return as an array of JSON objects in PHP?

`[
    {"hours":6,"day":"FRI"},
    {"hours":3,"day":"WEDS"},
    {"hours":6,"day":"MON"},
    {"hours":9,"day":"THUR"},
    {"hours":12,"day":"TUES"},
    {"hours":3,"day":"FRI"}
]`

I'm using the Slim Framework, mainly to handle the route calls.

My PHP is as follows:

```
function getHoursbyId($id) {

    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

    $query = 'SELECT hours, day FROM prof_hours
              JOIN professors ON professors.id=prof_hours.prof_id
              WHERE professors.id=?;';

    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

    if($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->bind_result($hours, $day);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $result['hours'] = $hours;
            $result['day'] = $day;

            echo jsonResponse('200', $result);

        }

        $stmt->close();

        return $result;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }

}
```

`$result` is an array and is passed into the function `jsonResponse()`

```
function jsonResponse($httpStatus, $response) {
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
$app->status($httpStatus);

$app->contentType('application/json');

echo json_encode($response);
}
```

I'm assuming somewhere in the jsonResponse lies my problem, but how would I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to fix the PHP script:

Now you're printing each item separately.

Instead, build an array of those, and at the very end, echo it with `json_encode()`.

```
$items = array();

// adding (in the loop)
$items[] = array('hours'=>$hours, 'day'=>$day);

// at the end
echo json_encode($items);
```

Then you will get valid JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are echo'ing the jsonResponse for every row. So currently for every row that you are getting from your database you are asking your application to echo its `json_encode`'d value. Which is why you are getting a non-delimited string of json objects.

What you need to do is build all of the rows into 1 array then send it to the output function.

Try:

```
...

$results = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $results[] = array(
        'hours' => $hours,
        'day' => $day
    );
}
echo jsonResponse('200', $results);
...
```